# choosing Fernet encryption algorithm

Tags: python, encryption, fernet

I'm using **Fernet**, and confused with **cipher algorithms**..  how can i try **AES**, **DES**, **Twofish**, **RC4** or other algorithms while generating my key.
(sorry if messed up:| just new to cipher :)

```
>>> from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
>>> key = Fernet.generate_key()
>>> f = Fernet(key)
>>> token = f.encrypt(b"my deep dark secret")
>>> token
b'...'
>>> f.decrypt(token)
b'my deep dark secret'
```

Comment: You can't -- Fernet uses AES only.

Comment: oh my bad!! so searching for other packages or idk what ever. Thanks you sir @President James K. Polk :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can not use other encryption algorithms with **Fernet** as in Fernet [Dosc](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/#implementation) says, you can only **AES**.